# How to get a unique list of associated results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I want to search for a Product and get all the categories from all the products from the search result to create a filter interface like github (The "Languages" menu in the sidebar).

```
@products = Product.product_search(params[:q])
@categories = ?
```

I want to list all categories from the products in the @products array.

Any idea whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

```
@categories = @products.map(&:category).compact.uniq
```

Comment: I allready tried something like that. But the method "categories" isn't defined for the @Products array :/. Products.categories (to get all categories, works) I can't use the .association functions for search results

Comment: First, use uppercase for models, lowercase for variables. Second, do you have an association between Product and Category? If Product has_many :categories, then my solution will work.

Comment: Thanks for the uppercase/lowercase advice, I'm new to all this stuff.
Product belongs_to :category, I think thats the Problem. Is there a solution for this kind of association?

Comment: Look at your log for SQL queries though. If you have access to product_search, try to add includes(:category) to the list so that products include categories in a single query.